# Is there any way to getting selenium to click on below link (ng-click) using python?

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

I have the following html with multiple links that use similar class and id and I want to click on the link which has 'toh'  with python selenium.

```css
<div Class="ibox-content">
  <ul Class="sortable-list policy-list">
    <li Class="success-element" id ng-click=
    "showReport($event,policy['toh'].policyCode,policy['toh']
    .policyName,policy['toh'].policyCurrencyCode);" style=
    "background-color: rgba(37, 128, 219, 0.2);">
                                    TOH
                                 </li> 
    <li Class="success-element" id ng-click=
    "showReport($event,policy['cuso'].policyCode,policy['cuso']
    .policyName,policy['cuso'].policyCurrencyCode);" style=
    "background-color: rgba(37, 128, 219, 0.2);">
                                    CUSO
                                 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of xpath

```
//div[@class='ibox-content']//ul//li[1]
```

This works as shown in the image below

[image]

In your python

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ibox-content']//ul//li[1]");
```

Or use below CSS selector

```
.ibox-content ul li
```

Works as shown in the image below
[image]

In your python

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ibox-content ul li");
```